# How to change iOS appearance on runtime using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Any good way to switch appearance from light to dark or vice versa on runtime without affecting performance? Currently, the appearance is checked on view load this brings the issue when iOS automatically changes the appearance or if the user manually clicks the appearance toggle and changes it.

I was trying to do on button click but the app was facing significant performance issues because it's checking every time when a button is clicked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `traitCollectionDidChange`:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
  
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            guard traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) else {
                return
            }

            // change your VC's apperance here
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the trigger for this method? Because without triggering this method won't start. For example, background thread, timer or more.

Comment: When the user changes the appearance, this method gets called.

Comment: What if the appearance is set to auto change. How will we detect that?

Comment: Same way. Quoting from the documentation: `The system calls this method when the iOS interface environment changes.` - this applies to _all_ trait changes, regardless of why they changed.